# Speech to text using asp.net mvc we b application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there any way or application which support speech to text in asp.net mvc web application and support in all browser ?

I have tried Google speech which support only Google chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

```
string threadMessage = null;
    bool returnValue = true;

    var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            SpeechEngine.SetOutputToWaveFile(wavFilePath);
            SpeechEngine.Speak(text);
            SpeechEngine.SetOutputToNull();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            threadMessage = "Error doing text to speech to file: " + exception.Message;
            returnValue = false;
        }
    });
    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    if (!returnValue)
    {
        message = threadMessage;
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: can i get full app if you have ?